# My boolean is returning false every time, c++ , arrays, Magic Box

Tags: c++, arrays, methods, boolean

Pretty much my output is correct, im reading i arrays from a file and summing up their row, column, and diagonal totals. Everything works fine except for my boolean value of isMagic(). if all the sums are equal then return true and if not then return false;

when coding the method for the right and left diagonal sums I entered (int size) because it would not allow me to compare those ints with rowTotal(row) and colTotal(col).. as far as I can tell this does not effect my overall code. I just need the boolean to return correctly. Any ideas?

```
// Purpose:  Magic BOX...
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int size= 0;
int box [][10]= {};

void ReadIn(ifstream& fin)
{
    box[size][size];
        for(int i = 0; i<size;++i)
        {
            for(int j= 0; j<size;++j)
                fin>> box[i][j];
        }
    cout<<"\n";
}

int rowTotal(int row)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<size; ++i)
        total+= box[row][i];
    return total;
}

int colTotal(int col)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        total += box[i][col];
    return total;
}

int rightdiagonal(int size)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        total+= box[i][i];
        return total;
}

int leftdiagonal(int size)
{
    int total = 0;
    int j=size-1;
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        {
            total+= box[i][j];
            j--;
        }
        return total;
}
bool isMagic()
{
    if(rowTotal != rightdiagonal)
        return false;
    if(colTotal != rightdiagonal)
        return false;
    if(rightdiagonal != leftdiagonal)
        return false;

    else return true;
}

void print(int& count)
    {
        int row=0, col=0;
        cout<< "==========="<<"\n"<< "===Box "<< count<<"==="<<"\n"<<"==========="<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j<size; ++j)
                        {
                            cout<<box[i][j]<<" ";
                        }
                    cout<<"\n";
                }
        cout<<"\n";

    }


int main()
{
    int count = 1;
    ifstream fin ("magicbox.txt");
    fin>>size;

    while(size != -1)
    {
        ReadIn(fin);
        print(count);
                for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
                {
                    int row=0;
                    rowTotal(row);
                    cout<<"The sum of row "<< row<< " is "<< rowTotal(row)<< endl;
                    row++;
                }
        cout<< "\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                {
                    int col=0;
                    colTotal(col);
                    cout<<"The sum of column "<< col<< " is "<< colTotal(col)<< endl;
                    col++;
                }   
            cout<<"\n";
            rightdiagonal(size);
            cout<<"The sum of the right diagonal is " << rightdiagonal(size)<< endl;

            leftdiagonal(size);
            cout<<"The sum of the left diagonal is " << leftdiagonal(size)<< endl;
        isMagic();
        if(isMagic() == true)
            cout<<"This matrix IS a magic box!"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"This matrix is NOT a magic box."<< endl;

        fin>>size;  
        count++;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think "box [size][size]" will do? Your array is a static variable with one row (or maybe zero rows) and ten columns.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to strip code to the smallest code that demonstrates the issue. Very often this adds clarity and you can solve yourself.

Comment: Yes, I don't know what you think `box[size][size]` is doing, but it definitely isn't doing that. _Please_ start indenting properly (this physically hurts to read), especially in conditional blocks; GCC 6 would have a field day with this code due to how misleading some of your indentation is - and it might cause you a very _bad_ day later. For the same reason, please consider always using braces around conditional blocks, as omitting them where _possible_ just invites horrifying errors later where you really _shouldn't_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is totally wrong

```
bool isMagic()
{
    if(rowTotal != rightdiagonal)
        return false;
    if(colTotal != rightdiagonal)
        return false;
    if(rightdiagonal != leftdiagonal)
        return false;

    else return true;
}
```

rowTotal and rightdiagonal are functions. It means nothing to compare them

YOu mean

```
bool isMagic()
{
int rd = rightDiagonal(size);
int ld = leftDiagonal(size);
if(ld != rd)
   return false;

// etc
}
```

You need to do a lot of column total and row total summing too

also you dont need to pass size into the totalling functions, its a global variable

Comment: since I returned them as ints I thought they were considered integer values?

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome: Notice in the solution, results of the function calls are stored in integers.  The integers are then compared.  A comparison returns `bool` type.  You need to review on the syntax for executing functions.